# Python: Split file by line match

Tags: python, file, io

I have a text file with different sections I would like to split in separate files . In the example below split point would be the "Step" lines.

```
Step Number: 1; Plot Name: deg0_R58; Type: Arrow Plot 
x(mm),y(mm),z(mm),Bx(T),By(T),Bz(T),Bm(T)
5.505E+01,-1.124E-02,-2.000E+00, 3.443E-04,-1.523E-05, 3.913E-04
5.511E+01,-1.124E-02,-2.000E+00, 3.417E-04,-1.511E-05, 3.912E-04
5.516E+01,-1.124E-02,-2.000E+00, 3.390E-04,-1.499E-05, 3.910E-04
...

Step Number: 2; Plot Name: deg0_R58; Type: Arrow Plot
...
```

The reason for this is that the pandas function `pandas.read_csv()` will not work on the entire file because of the "Step" lines.

I only need the files temporarily for the `pandas.read_csv()` so I don't actually want to write them.
I've tried slicing the file with `itertools.islice` but then I can't process the output with `pandas.read_csv` because it needs a file type object.

Here is what I've got so far:

```
buf  = []
with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
            if 'Step' in line:
                buf.append( [] )
            else:
                buf[-1].append( line )
```

Is there a way to get `buf` list of lines into a file type format?

->

Thanks for the input, StringIO works great!
Here's what I made of it just in case anyone is facing a similar problem:

```
steps_Dict= {}
fsection = None
step_nr = 0;
with open( filepath, 'r' ) as f:
    print f
    for line in f:
        if 'Step' in line:
            if fsection:
                step_nr = step_nr + 1   # Steps start with 1
                fsection.seek(0)
                steps_Dict[ step_nr ] = pd.read_csv(fsection, sep=',', header=0 )
                print steps_Dict
            fsection = StringIO.StringIO()  # new section
        else:   # append to section
            if line.strip():                                # Skip Blank Lines;Alternative with pandas 0.16, pd.read_csv skip_blank_lines=True a parameter could be used ?
                fsection.write( line )  
    if fsection:    # captures the last section
        fsection.seek(0)
        steps_Dict[ step_nr +1] = pd.read_csv( fsection, sep=',', header=0 )
steps_Panel = pd.Panel( steps_Dict )
```

Comment: You could save it as a temporary file, load it, and then delete it. It's a little much, but a straightforward approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [StringIO](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) to store the string if you don't need to write into a file.

```
import StringIO

output = StringIO.StringIO()
with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if 'Step' not in line:
            output.write(line)
```

Then you can use Pandas' `read_csv` function with `output`.

As @Julien pointed out in the comment below. You also need to do `output.seek(0)` before reading it with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
output.seek(0)
pd.read_csv(output)
```

Comment: looks like you beat me by 18 seconds :-)

Comment: @JulienSpronck I almost thought you beat me haha ;)

Comment: Make sure you rewind your output file with `output.seek(0)` before using `read_csv`. Otherwise, pandas will think that the file is empty.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `StringIO` module to create a file-like object that can be used by `pd.read_csv()`:

```
import StringIO
import pandas as pd

astr = StringIO.StringIO()
astr.write('This,is,a,test\n')
astr.write('This,is,another,test\n')
astr.seek(0)
df = pd.read_csv(astr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`pandas.io.parsers.read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html) function and skip the lines you don't need or want and read the file directly into a `DataFrame`.

```
 import pandas
 z = pandas.io.parsers.read_csv("C:/path/a.txt", skiprows=0, header=1, sep=",")
 z

    x(mm)   y(mm)       z(mm)   Bx(T)       By(T)       Bz(T)       Bm(T)
0   55.05   -0.01124    -2      0.000344    -0.000015   0.000391    NaN
1   55.11   -0.01124    -2      0.000342    -0.000015   0.000391    NaN
2   55.16   -0.01124    -2      0.000339    -0.000015   0.000391    NaN
```